# Lua in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, c++, ios, lua, cocos2d-x

I am new in `cocos2d` development. I developed some stuff on `andengine` on Android and I know C++ language. Now I want to rewrite some stuff from `andengine` and make it available to iOS as well. I am reading and reading and testing from couple of days, everything is just ok, but few days ago I explored `Lua`. I adopted language semantics, wrote some scripts and realized that in Internet there is a lot of usage of this language. It is so common that I cannot believe that I know about it from couple of days. So I thought that would be nice if I try to use it. I have only few questions for now.

1. Can I load some `Lua` scripts and use it in my `cocos2d-x` game (written in C++)?
2. What is the difference between `cocos2d-x` 2.x and new 3.x beta branch (about Lua treating off course)?
3. I think about `Lua` only as way to implement AI for now (is this so good idea or not necessary?). I think it could be good idea because it is portable and I can use very the same AI algorithms for different platform (andorid, iOs, windows, linux, web...).

Please just give me some light about usage of `Lua` in `cocos2d-x`, because I cannot find any sense tutorials. If there is something the headers are bad, or version is deprecated or something else which is really annoying when you have no clue how to use it.

Maybe better is to write entire project in lua?

Comment: You're asking several different, open-ended questions at once. 1. is unclear (yes?), 2. should be in the change log, if it's not assume it hasn't changed, 3. and the final question are both subjective. 
This question is not a good fit for SO. Try to focus on a specific issue that can be answered authoritatively.

Comment: You can load Lua script in C++ project.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

1. Yes.
2. What do you mean?
3. It works.

As LearnCocos2D suggested, they cover too much and are not good questions. I suppose you're wondering if you would like to use cocos2d or cocos2d with lua. I suggest you take a look at quick-cocos2d-x, because you mentioned cross-platform AI and it worths to have a look.